# Resolving arrays of tuples in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to transform

```
({(A1),(A2)},{(A1-002),(A2-046)},{(124,323)})
```

into:

```
(A1,A1-002,124)
(A1,A1-002,323)
(A2,A2-046,124)
(A2,A2-046,323)
```

So that for each of the third elements, the first two elements are paired up in order.
I originally tried to flatten each of them, like

```
a = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(first) AS first, FLATTEN(second) AS second, FLATTEN(third) AS third;
```

but the order is not preserved.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!